# C# Dependency Injection problem

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have 3 classes: A, B, and C

All of these classes implement an interface IMyInterface

I would like the interface to be defined like so:

```
internal IMyInterface<E> where E: class
{
    E returnData();
}
```

So that it can return data of type E.
The type "E" will be a POCO object created with the Entity Framework v4.

In a separate class I have:

```
public class MyClass()
{
   IMyInterface<??> businessLogic;

   public setBusinessLogic(IMyInterface<E> myObject)
       where E : class
   {
       businessLogic = myObject;
   }
}
```

I tried putting `<object>` in place of `<??>` but it could not cast my poco entity type.

I tried having my entities implement an empty interface `IEntity` then using

```
IMyInterface<IEntity> businessLogic;
...
businessLogic = new A<POCOObject>();
```

results in:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type
 'A<POCOObject>' to
 'IMyInterface<IEntity>'. An explicit
 conversion exists (are you missing a
 cast?)
```

Any recommendations?

**Edit:** I've tried declaring my A, B, and C classes as:

```
internal class A : IBidManager<EntityObjectType>
```

and

```
internal class A<E> : IBidManager<E> where E : class
```

results in the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will have to be either

```
public class MyClass<E> where E : IEntity, class
{
   IMyInterface<E> businessLogic;

   public setBusinessLogic(IMyInterface<E> myObject)
   {
       businessLogic = myObject;
   }
}
```

or

```
 public class MyClass
{
   IMyInterface<POCOObject> businessLogic;

   public setBusinessLogic(IMyInterface<POCOObject> myObject)
   {
       businessLogic = myObject;
   }
}
```

If you wnt your business object to handle any POCO object and they each have an interface then you will need to specify `where E : class, IEntity` at the class level. Otherwise you have yo use concrete type for the generic arg

Comment: Hrmm initially it was working when I just did IBidManager<IEntity> businessLogic;   then did businessLogic = (IBidManager<IEntity>)new A(); .... but for some reason it isnt working anymore...

Comment: Although the solutions above work, I cannot do them that way. In the first example you use <E> in the class definition. Our system isn't setup to work that way. I want to create a class, and then call a function to change the IMyInterface object to reference something else. In the second example its not dynamic, the POCOObject is different for A, B, and C

Comment: It's telling me an explicit conversion exists... hrmm

Comment: Yes, because you want IMyInteface<E> as a field in the class the class needs the generic argument. Since you want to swap in different objects then having them share a common interface would work. I have not dabbled with c#4 so not sure if the covarience/contravarience conversions would help. Not knowing what your business object does I would think at some level an interface would need to exist so you can deal with different implementations. 
I think even if you try explicit conversion then you will need to convert it to a known type which in your generic class would get ugly.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. went for a run ;)

Comment: covariance worked... in my interface I just set it to IMyInterface<out E> where E : IEntity ... thanks :)